# How to filter a dataframe based on another dataframes index

Tags: python, dataframe

I am building a ML Model

There is 2 datasets `X_test` and `y_test`

Here how they look like

```
X_test
Out[19]: 
      AJ3158003  SY0942007  WW3873005  ...  LZ014003  QP4868006   RepID
9072          5          5          5  ...         0          0  292715
2296         10         10         10  ...         0          8  239729
6333          7          7          7  ...        -1         -2   98758
8631          8          8          8  ...        -1          0  261983
8420          5          5          5  ...         0          0  248760
        ...        ...        ...  ...       ...        ...     ...
4417          9          9          9  ...        -1         -1  300160
4028          9          9          9  ...         0          0  138284
5881          9          9          9  ...         0          0   66981
9052          5          5          5  ...         0          0  291510
1106          5          5          5  ...         0          0  153736
```

and `y_test` looks like this

```
y_test
Out[21]: 
9072    1
2296    0
6333    1
8631    1
8420    1
       ..
4417    0
4028    0
5881    1
9052    1
1106    0
Name: ABCL, Length: 1932, dtype: int32
```

You can see that Indecies in both dataframe as match with order (Match length and order of records)

What I did is that I filtered `X_test` based on a third dataset called `dfDone`

```
X_test = X_test[~X_test.RepID.isin(dfDone.RepID)]
```

Now `X_test` and `y_test` do not match

I want to filter `y_test` so it only keeps the records that match the index of the filtered `X_test`

How to do that?